# How do I display page numbers in a book?

Tags: nodes

I have my nodes organized using the book module. I would like to be able to display the page number at the bottom of the page. The pages would be numbered according to the order in the book outline. Is this possible? I even tried looking for a PHP code snippet I could put in book-navigation.tpl.php or similar.

Comment: if you re-arrange a books' pages -- wouldn't the page numbers be meaningless? (you can re-arrange a books' content).

Comment: Its an online text book so I mostly just edit pages. You are right that inserting a page at the beginning would cause all the pages to re-number. However, its rare that I do that.

Comment: I looked into it. There kinda is no easy way (due to the "bug" i outline above). I can think of a few solutions but they would be hackish and likely difficult to implement. I know of no such module you can install to do this now without custom code.

Comment: Can anyone give answer/solution for this question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053338/how-to-add-numbering-numbers-to-drupal-8-book-child-pages-or-book-outlined-pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple PHP code in your node.tpl.php

```
    <?php
      $allbook = book_toc($node->book['bid'],3);
     $allbook_chapter = array_search($node->book['mlid'], array_keys($allbook));
print $allbook_chapter;
            ?>
```

This code prints page number of current node. This in't better way of course. 
Moving this logic to template.php is better solution.